# How to correct stroke position when drawing on canvas with image? with typescript Angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typescript, canvas

[image]I added an image to a canvas. I want to draw on the image, but when drawing a line, it does not appear above the mouse pointer.  The canvas container has a method to verify the correct position of the mouse inside the canvas and it is correct, but the drawn line appears far below the mouse pointer. How can I make the drawing stroke, where is the mouse pointer?

public canvas() {

```
let x;
let y;



//we determine the location of the mouse within the canvas
$('#mycanvas').mousemove(function(e){

  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
  y = e.clientY - rect.top;  //y position within the element.
  console.log("X : " + x );
  console.log("Y : " + y );
});



const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.querySelector("#mycanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


//Agregamos imagen al canvas
const image = new Image();
image.src = 'assets/img/human.png';
image.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 150);
}



//paint
let painting = false;


//starting position
function startPosition(e) {
  
  painting = true;
  
  draw(e);
}

//final position
function finishedPosition() {
  painting = false;
  
  ctx.beginPath();
}


function draw(e) {
  
  if(!painting) {
    return;
  }

  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";


  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();


  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
}

//EventListeners
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finishedPosition);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw)
```

}

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: of course, but you won't see where the mouse pointer is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function and pass the event argument to it. to get absolute x,y on canvas element.

```
function getPosition(e) {
   this.boundingRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); // canvas = canvas element
   return {
     x : (e.targetTouches) ? e.targetTouches[0].pageX - this.boundingRect.x : e.offsetX,
     y : (e.targetTouches) ? e.targetTouches[0].pageY - this.boundingRect.y : e.offsetY,
   };  
}
```

For optimization you can cache `this.boundingRect` variable, because getBoundingClientRect operation is time consuming

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Add inside $ ("# mycanvas"),      x = (e.targetTouches) ? e.targetTouches[0].pageX - this.boundingRect.x : e.offsetX; y = (e.targetTouches) ? e.targetTouches[0].pageY - this.boundingRect.y : e.offsetY; but the result did not change